Add reference to glossary entry but with different text
Is there a way to add a reference to a glossary entry, but using a text different than the one indicated on the entry?
For example, I'd like something like this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{gls:algo} {
  name={Algorithm},
  description={This is the definition of an algorithm.}
}

\begin{document}

Such an astounding \gls[gl:algo]{algorithmical} trick.

It makes for a part of an interesting \gls[gl:algo]{algorithm}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}

